# crear subdominios desde landingpage

Tags: javascript, html, cpanel, subdominio

me gustaria hacer la funcionalidad de crear subdominios, desde una landing que el usuario  se conecte y genere el subdominio y le muestre los datos de acceso, actualmente lo hago en cpanel de forma manual, se podra automatizar? Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Usa la [API de cpanel](https://api.docs.cpanel.net/) para ello.

Comment: muchas gracias!